# How to turn this code into a one-liner or make it shorter?

Tags: python

I am a middle school student and just started learning about functions. This code is about exponents, but I cannot use import math. Is there a way to make this code into a one-liner or make it shorter?

```
def power(a, n):
    x = 1
    if n == 0:
        print(1)
    elif n > 0:
        for i in range(n):
            x = x * a
    else:
        for i in range(-n):
            x = x * a

    return x


print(power(2, 5))
```

Comment: There's builtin function ```pow(base, exp)``` in python.

Comment: Or you know, good old `base**exp`.

Comment: @Prometheus That's... why couldn't I think of it?

Comment: Here's cursed power function ```func = (lambda base, exp: (lambda ff: ff(ff, base, exp))(lambda f, n, p: 1 if p == 0 else n if p == 1 else ((lambda x: x*x)(f(f, n, p//2))*(n if p % 2 == 1 else 1))))``` in single line without ```pow``` or ```**```

Comment: If you don't want to use `**` you could at least drop the `elif` part and change the loop in the `else` path to `for i in range(abs(n)):`. And of course `print(1)` has to be replaced by `return 1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the pow function instead of "x = x * a". Also even if you don't want to use that function, you can simplify it as "x *= a".

Comment: How can that be the accepted answer - and have up votes - when it is obivously wrong and has been posted after @Prometheus' correct comment?
Or am I missing something?
I mean `x *= a` is a shorthand for `x = x * a`, but that's multiplication not exponentiation which was the original question, right?

Answer (score 4):

You could look into recursive functions, they are a bit tricky at first but are a good brain exercise.
A recursive power function would look like that :

```
def power(a, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n == 1:
        return a
    else:
        return a * power(a, n-1)
```

Comment: sure but you really shouldn't use this in Python

Comment: that's true; but being a student myself i've been asked to make functions just like this one to practice the logic more than the actual usability of the function

Answer (score 3):

You can use the in-built operator `**`.

Example:

```
print(2**2) # Will return 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `**` operator directly:

```
print(2 ** 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to shorten your function with one line, you can use lambda statements like this: [Shortening code with lambda statement in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921406/how-to-shorten-my-code-with-lambda-statement-in-python)

And you can use the ** builtin operator in place of multiplying the number over and over in a loop. So for example, 5**4 is equivalent to 5 * 5 * 5 * 5 and will give the exact same output.

P.S. I am also just beginning with programming, so I might not have the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

`**`

which will return the value of 4 to the power of 3 (same as 4 * 4 * 4):

Answer (score 1):

You can use `**` This is an exponentiation operator.

```
def power(a, n):
    return a**n
print(power(2, 5))
```

or simply use lambda function. You can [read about it here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp).

```py
print((lambda x,y:x**y)(2,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to use your own function. You can shorter an if with:

```
value_when_true if condition else value_when_false;
```

[Putting a simple if-then-else statement on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802726/putting-a-simple-if-then-else-statement-on-one-line)

Answer (score 0):

I can see your overall need is to get the power of x.

If you can't use import math, then go with the inbuilt arithmetic operator for exponential that is **

Ex. You need 5 to the power 4 then code will be

```
print(5**4) # In one line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def power(b,n):
    n=abs(n)
    print(b**n)
print(power(2,-5))
```

well how about this here you can use the abs function to convert negative number to positive so no need for extra code simple use of ** can do everything